# using CSS3 linear-gradient from alpha to a colour

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

I am looking for a way to make a linear-gradient from "nothing" (alpha) to a defined colour: #e6a015. I can't find it neither in google nor here, can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rgba colour with alpha as zero

```
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top left, rgba(230,160,21,0) 0%, rgb(230,160,21)  100%);

/* Mozilla Firefox */ 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, rgba(230,160,21,0) 0%, rgb(230,160,21) 100%);

/* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top left, rgba(230,160,21,0) 0%, rgb(230,160,21) 100%);

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0, rgba(230,160,21,0)), color-stop(1, rgb(230,160,21)));

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, rgba(230,160,21,0) 0%,rgb(230,160,21) 100%);

/* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(230,160,21,0) 0%, rgb(230,160,21) 100%);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XHt6C/)

Comment: how can i make the glow come from the bottom?